# Users required to reset their password even after System admin has set the password

Tags: passwords

I have set passwords (from Dev Console) for around 50 users in my org, however when they login they are being redirected to reset password page. I want them to be able to directly login into SFDC with the new password i set, how can i make them bypass the reset password page?

Comment: when you create login to the user, from the email they recieve, they can direclt enter new password and login to sandbox.

Comment: @Anurag - I have set the Password from Dev Console using Set password method. So they are not going to get any email.

Comment: Please go through the article, http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000230624

Comment: Yeah, I did see that, seems like I cant really have users bypass the reset page even if i (as sys admin) set their passwords. huh...

Comment: Ya as per the doc., it seems that, this is the way its designed. So I'm not sure whether we have any work around for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design in Salesforce - the System Administrator is not meant to know user passwords so even if you set the password for the user using the Developer Console it will still prompt them to change that password that has been entered.

So you will not be able to avoid the users being sent to the change password page.

> This is Working as Designed (WAD) in salesforce. If you hit enter you are actually hitting the 'cancel' button. The "Save" button doesn't get enabled until the requirements for the page are met (value entered for current password, matching & valid new & confirm passwords and/or a value for the security answer). The password of the user has not been changed.

[Salesforce Help](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000230624)